# Web3 Development - Patrick C. Error HH110: Invalid JSON-RPC response received: project id required in the url

Tags: javascript, web3js

I'm currently following Patrick C. Web3 development tutorial. I would have cloned the github repo for lesson 9 and and changed what needed to be changed. After running yarn `hardhat deploy --network goerli`, the terminal would output: **Error HH110: Invalid JSON-RPC response received: project id required in the url**.

**Code for 01-deploy-raffle.js:**

```
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
    VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

const FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("1") // 1 Ether, or 1e18 (10^18) Wei

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock

    if (chainId == 31337) {
        // create VRFV2 Subscription
        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address
        const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait()
        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId
        // Fund the subscription
        // Our mock makes it so we don't actually have to worry about sending fund
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, FUND_AMOUNT)
    } else {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }
    const waitBlockConfirmations = developmentChains.includes(network.name)
        ? 1
        : VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS

    log("----------------------------------------------------")
    const arguments = [
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
        subscriptionId,
        networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["keepersUpdateInterval"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["raffleEntranceFee"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"],
    ]
    const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
        from: deployer,
        args: arguments,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: waitBlockConfirmations,
    })

    // Verify the deployment
    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying...")
        await verify(raffle.address, arguments)
    }

    log("Enter lottery with command:")
    const networkName = network.name == "hardhat" ? "localhost" : network.name
    log(`yarn hardhat run scripts/enterRaffle.js --network ${networkName}`)
    log("----------------------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"]
```

**Code for helper-hardhat-config.js:**

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

const networkConfig = {
    default: {
        name: "hardhat",
        keepersUpdateInterval: "30",
    },
    31337: {
        name: "localhost",
        subscriptionId: "4640",
        gasLane: "0xd89b2bf150e3b9e13446986e571fb9cab24b13cea0a43ea20a6049a85cc807cc", // 30 gwei
        keepersUpdateInterval: "30",
        raffleEntranceFee: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"), // 0.1 ETH
        callbackGasLimit: "500000", // 500,000 gas
    },
    5: {
        name: "goerli",
        subscriptionId: "4640",
        gasLane: "0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15", // 30 gwei
        keepersUpdateInterval: "30",
        raffleEntranceFee: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"), // 0.1 ETH
        callbackGasLimit: "500000", // 500,000 gas
        vrfCoordinatorV2: "0x2Ca8E0C643bDe4C2E08ab1fA0da3401AdAD7734D",
    },
    1: {
        name: "mainnet",
        keepersUpdateInterval: "30",
    },
}

const developmentChains = ["hardhat", "localhost"]
const VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS = 6
const frontEndContractsFile = "../nextjs-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/constants/contractAddresses.json"
const frontEndAbiFile = "../nextjs-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/constants/abi.json"

module.exports = {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
    VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS,
    frontEndContractsFile,
    frontEndAbiFile,
}
```

**Code for hardhat.config.js:**

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
require("hardhat-deploy")
require("solidity-coverage")
require("hardhat-gas-reporter")
require("hardhat-contract-sizer")
require("dotenv").config()

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */

const MAINNET_RPC_URL =
    process.env.MAINNET_RPC_URL ||
    process.env.ALCHEMY_MAINNET_RPC_URL ||
    "https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/your-api-key"
const GOERLI_RPC_URL =
    process.env.GOERLI_RPC_URL || "https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/your-api-key"
const POLYGON_MAINNET_RPC_URL =
    process.env.POLYGON_MAINNET_RPC_URL || "https://polygon-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/your-api-key"
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY || "0x"
// optional
const MNEMONIC = process.env.MNEMONIC || "your mnemonic"

// Your API key for Etherscan, obtain one at https://etherscan.io/
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY || "Your etherscan API key"
const POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY || "Your polygonscan API key"
const REPORT_GAS = process.env.REPORT_GAS || false

module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            // // If you want to do some forking, uncomment this
            // forking: {
            //   url: MAINNET_RPC_URL
            // }
            chainId: 31337,
        },
        localhost: {
            chainId: 31337,
        },
        goerli: {
            url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
            accounts: PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
            //   accounts: {
            //     mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
            //   },
            saveDeployments: true,
            chainId: 5,
        },
        mainnet: {
            url: MAINNET_RPC_URL,
            accounts: PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
            //   accounts: {
            //     mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
            //   },
            saveDeployments: true,
            chainId: 1,
        },
        polygon: {
            url: POLYGON_MAINNET_RPC_URL,
            accounts: PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
            saveDeployments: true,
            chainId: 137,
        },
    },
    etherscan: {
        // yarn hardhat verify --network <NETWORK> <CONTRACT_ADDRESS> <CONSTRUCTOR_PARAMETERS>
        apiKey: {
            goerli: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
            polygon: POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY,
        },
    },
    gasReporter: {
        enabled: REPORT_GAS,
        currency: "USD",
        outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
        noColors: true,
        // coinmarketcap: process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
    },
    contractSizer: {
        runOnCompile: false,
        only: ["Raffle"],
    },
    namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
            default: 0, // here this will by default take the first account as deployer
            1: 0, // similarly on mainnet it will take the first account as deployer. Note though that depending on how hardhat network are configured, the account 0 on one network can be different than on another
        },
        player: {
            default: 1,
        },
    },
    solidity: {
        compilers: [
            {
                version: "0.8.7",
            },
            {
                version: "0.4.24",
            },
        ],
    },
    mocha: {
        timeout: 500000, // 500 seconds max for running tests
    },
}
```

Comment: are you sure you have defined RPC URL in your `.env`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your GOERLI_RPC_URL isn't defined correctly in your .env
It should look something like

```
https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/{your-api-key}
```

`{your-api-key}` should be some hash that's your alchemy API.
You can find that in your alchemy dashboard.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34010593)